# Problema BrokenProcessPool en python

Tags: python

Hola a todos estoy creando un código de ejemplo que me crea un processpool que duerme el programa por el tiempo que le ingrese en el arreglo secs:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

def do_something (seconds):
    print(f'Sleeping {seconds} seconds(s)...' )
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'Done Sleeping...{seconds}'

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        secs=[5,4,3,2,1]
        results=[executor.submit(do_something, sec) for sec in secs]

        for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
            print(f.result())
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

pero al ejecutarlo me aparece lo siguiente:

```
BrokenProcessPool                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-53d8fc670e89> in <module>
     16 
     17 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 18     main()

<ipython-input-1-53d8fc670e89> in main()
     13 
     14         for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
---> 15             print(f.result())
     16 
     17 if __name__ == '__main__':

~\.conda\envs\automa\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in result(self, timeout)
    426                 raise CancelledError()
    427             elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 428                 return self.__get_result()
    429 
    430             self._condition.wait(timeout)

~\.conda\envs\automa\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py in __get_result(self)
    382     def __get_result(self):
    383         if self._exception:
--> 384             raise self._exception
    385         else:
    386             return self._result

BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

Estuve leyendo un poco y encontré que para windows es necesario proteger el programa es por ello le agregue la función main, no obstante me sigue apareciendo el mismo problema.
Alguien me podría indicar que estay haciendo mal ?
Gracias.

Comment: Lo probe en Linux Mint y funciona OK.

Comment: lo estoy ejecutando en un jupyter notebook en windows, y me aparece eso, alguna idea del porque ?